# Add REG_EXPAND_SZ with multiple quoted values by REG.EXE only

Tags: cmd.exe, windows-registry

**EDIT: RESOLVED.**
Needed to escape all special characters and put quotes around all paths containing spaces.  Working CMD code below for reference.

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\ServiceName" /v ImagePath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Program Directory\ServiceName.exe\" \"?e=Access^&y=Guest^&h=sub.domain.com^&p=8041^&s=53f091fb-b92e-4716-80a3-29fafb53a253^&k=BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAgAABEAAAALtBChA27KsME1zvRANc4%2bT14R0raas%2blcVFtdua4P03fn1qJNxFV4jNsw%2bfZrCqaut76dEO0sPsAeHpuD6m9oyGK4DOoYRvjKnsq8SYuyZvxF5%2fiUeINpqPT%2bQXUDJLBOo6oyXfj%2bFED7rS5wYFT98xPllsoD31jX%2bVlUmwXx5ll8ILGdVphd236iYxV32u%2fpnMXQHR3vr7oXZhdLp%2b3fqap96%2bbFebjhKFg03bHnbK%2fQdbeFNcwntK34oAMq%2f1PB64gAeYucxkXNTaDoLRoWceP61uKwF9IIh58svm501OCDMfwbmUsigpXS9NawISpGqbjRe9DvXP7oGX1S79aT^&t=^&c=ANEW^&c=^&c=^&c=^&c=^&c=^&c=^&c="" /f
```

I need to overwrite an existing REG_EXPAND_SZ string with a new one.  However the Value data for the string has two values which need to be enclosed in quotes and separated by a space. e.g.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Program Directory\ServiceName.exe" "?e=Access&y=Guest&h=sub.domain.com&p=8041&s=53f091fb-b92e-4716-80a3-29fafb53a253&k=BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAgAABEAAAALtBChA27KsME1zvRANc4%2bT14R0raas%2blcVFtdua4P03fn1qJNxFV4jNsw%2bfZrCqaut76dEO0sPsAeHpuD6m9oyGK4DOoYRvjKnsq8SYuyZvxF5%2fiUeINpqPT%2bQXUDJLBOo6oyXfj%2bFED7rS5wYFT98xPllsoD31jX%2bVlUmwXx5ll8ILGdVphd236iYxV32u%2fpnMXQHR3vr7oXZhdLp%2b3fqap96%2bbFebjhKFg03bHnbK%2fQdbeFNcwntK34oAMq%2f1PB64gAeYucxkXNTaDoLRoWceP61uKwF9IIh58svm501OCDMfwbmUsigpXS9NawISpGqbjRe9DvXP7oGX1S79aT&t=&c=ANEW&c=&c=&c=&c=&c=&c=&c="
```

I've tried loads of variations but keep getting a syntax error.

I'm constrained in that I cannot use PowerShell or batch files, just REG.EXE via CMD.  I'm really hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape ampersands with a caret (to avoid the command processor interpreting them as a command separator) and double-quotes with a backslash (to avoid `REG` interpreting them as string delimiters):

```
reg add HKCU\Path\To\Subkey /v SomeValueName /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /f /d "\"C:\some path\filename.exe\" \"?e=Access^&y=Guest...\""
```

You may need to escape percent signs as two percent signs as well in a batch file.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply.  I still get the Invalid Syntax error, however, when following the directions provided.

Even using the simple example you provided (appropriately edited) results in Invalid Syntax

Comment: @ColmWhelan Are there any other special characters in your actual command? [This command](https://pastebin.com/raw/KMeBcbsz) works for me (assuming you have a subkey called `Test` in HKCU), both at the prompt and in a batch file.

Comment: Oh, actually in a batch file it destroys the percent signs - those need to be doubled as harrymc's answer notes. I still can't reproduce a syntax error, though.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

- Use backslashes to escape the inner double-quotes, as described by
  [Ben N](https://superuser.com/a/1707921/8672).
  In general, the REG command will interpret `\` as an escape for the
  character that immediately follows it, to be used for all troublesome
  characters.
- Another alternative for double-quotes is to use
  single quotes (`'`), for applications that can use them properly.
- Percent literals must be doubled in a batch file: `\"%%1\" %%*"`
- If using PowerShell, to use a `"` inside a string is not `\"` but
  as `". Using a single-quote (if it works) is clearer.